# How to re-increment each id attribute in Formset after deleting a Form in Django?

Tags: javascript, django, python-3.x, django-forms, django-templates

I currently have a formset rendered to a template, where I do a for loop over it to display each form. I have a button which adds extra forms and I also have a delete button which removes any of the forms. My problem is when I delete one of the middle forms, the incrementing from the formset management (ie. `id="form-0-choice"`) gets thrown off. If I add 3 new forms, I now have `form 1, 2, 3`. If I delete `form 2` and then add another form, I now have `form 1, 3, 4`. Not all the forms will be saved correctly. How would I go about re-incrementing these id's? Is there a better way to manage creating/deleting in a formset manager on the template side? Or, would I need to just use JS to split apart the id's and re-number them based on the `TOTAL_NUM_FORMS` or however it is spelled.